# Update a value if a seperate key value pair is True

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

How do I update a `key, value pair` if the other `key, value pair` evaluates to true?

```
bank = {
    "88386180860608512" : {      # This is a unique id number
        "balance" : 100,
        "name" : "Aehnon"
    },
    "88469127777243136" : {     # This is a unique id number
        "balance" : 100,
        "name" : "Balanceofevil"
    },
    "89741285950246912" : {     # This is a unique id number
        "balance" : 3310,
        "name" : "Sharky"
    }
}
```

if my code gives me a list of names, ["Sharky", "Aehnon"], I need to increase the balance of those two users by 50. The issue is that I don't know their "id numbers".

For further clarifications I want to update every balance by 50 that has a matching `key, value` (I.E. "Name": Sharky is a match with the name "Sharky" in my list).

So far I know I can validate one name if I do this for example:

```
b  = [subdict["name"] for subdict in bank.values()]
if "Aehnon" in b:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False)
```

which evaluates to:

```
True
```

But I'm unsure how to do this dynamically with a larger list to update the balances.

Comment: The fastest/simplest way (assuming the names are unique) is to have a separate index to the unique number - eg {"Sharky" : "89741285950246912", ...})

Comment: The names aren't always unique. That is why each has an ID.

Comment: "Sharky" : [sharky_id_1, Sharky_id_2...] ? In effect, you are adding an index to the dictionary.

Comment: The structure of the dictionary is not something I'm allowed to change if that is what you mean.

Comment: No, you create another dictionary indexed by name containing an array of IDs that match that name. Then use those IDs to update the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
bank = {
    "88386180860608512" : {      # This is a unique id number
        "balance" : 100,
        "name" : "Aehnon"
    },
    "88469127777243136" : {     # This is a unique id number
        "balance" : 100,
        "name" : "Balanceofevil"
    },
    "89741285950246912" : {     # This is a unique id number
        "balance" : 3310,
        "name" : "Sharky"
    }
}

names = ["Sharky", "Aehnon"]

for v in bank.values():
    if v["name"] in names:
        v['balance'] += 50

print(bank)
```

Comment: This is working for me, and I replicated it on a larger scale to be sure. Can you walk me through your thought process of coming to this conclusion?

Comment: @Chad, first you need to iterate through all `bank` sub dicts: `for v in bank.values():`. Then you just check if current sub dict's 'name' in list of names you need: `if v["name"] in names`. And if so, you can update sub dict's `balance`: `v['balance'] += 50`

Comment: Ah I get it! Thank you for replying back.